# How to set Google Play Turn Based Multiplayer expire time

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games

Currently Turn Based Multiplayer games expire in 2 weeks. Is there an option to set it to another value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't set the expire time. The [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/turnbasedMultiplayer#match_states) states:

> A match expires when a user does not respond to an invitation or turn notification for two weeks. A match also expires in one day if there is an empty auto-match slot available but Google Play games services cannot find a user to auto-match.

There is a feature request to make it adjustable [on Github](https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples/issues/182), but sadly no recent activity.